# Passing slug from Template to View in django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, slug

I have an application wherin I am trying to pass a slug field from a template (*frames.html*) to the views.py. My problem is that I see the URL changing on clicking on the link on frames.html, but it doesn't seem to reach the view.(I have print statements in my views.py which are not getting printed, so that's how I know.). My *frames.html* is as follows

```
<div id="FramePage">
   {% for frame in Frames %}
     <p><a href="/frames/{{ frame.slug }}/">{{frame}}</a>                  
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

This is the entry in my *urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
# Examples:
#url(r'^$', 'vTryON_Django.views.home', name='home'),
# url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^$', 'vTryON.views.home_page'),
url(r'^frames/', 'vTryON.views.VTryONAll'),
url(r'^frames/(?P<frameslug>.*)/$', 'vTryON.views.selectedFrame'),
url(r'^tryonpage/', 'vTryON.views.tryonpage'),
url(r'^uploadPC/', 'vTryON.views.uploadPC'),
url(r'^uploadWebcam/', 'vTryON.views.uploadWebcam'),
```

)

and this is my view function in *views.py*

```
def selectedFrame(request, frameslug):
    #print('selectedFrame')
    frame= VTryON.objects.get(slug=frameslug)
    #print(frame)
    context={'frame':frame}
    #print('context')
    return render_to_response('selectedframe.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

As I mentioned, i can see my URL change from `http://127.0.0.1:8000/frames/` to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/frames/FR123/` after I click on the link on *frames.html*.
Am I configuring it wrongly in urls.py? I am a beginner in python /django. Please help me out.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Slow the rest of your urls.py, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your URLs. Your `frames` URL does not terminate the regex at the end. So it also matches anything that simply *starts* with "frames", which includes "frames/FR123".

You should ensure that all URLs explicitly end with `$` to prevent this.

```
url(r'^frames/$', 'vTryON.views.VTryONAll'),
```

Comment: Hi, i put $ in my url like you said. Now, I see that it goes to the views.py (The print statements get printed). However, when I try to render the response to template (selectedframe.html), it does give me the template. It gives me a TemplateDoesNotExist at /frames/fr123/, though I have the selectedframe.html in the templates folder. what could be the problem?